# Why this SqlParameterCollection call is throwing error?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

This is code sample to call a stored procedure. Second process throws `InvalidCastException` at runtime. I am trying to add a new `SqlParameter` into the `SqlParametersCollection`. I have seen lots of example using the same syntax.

```
using (SqlCommand db = new SqlCommand("[StoredProcedureName]"))
{
    db.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    db.Connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationAccess.ConnectionString);

    //1) works but this is long so wanted to try shortcut
    db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pID", SqlDbType.Int));
    db.Parameters["@pID"].Value = 12345;
    //2) <<>>throws InvalidCastExpception. Id is set up as Int32
    db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12345);
    //3)but following codes does the job
    db.Parameters.Add("@pID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12345;
    db.Connection.Open();
    var dr = db.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to solve the problem or just why a certain syntax fails?

Comment: @RonBeyer: Constructors *always* return values. That code is syntactically valid.

Comment: Sorry @JonSkeet I was thinking of something else, I removed it when I realized what junk my fingers spewed out.

Comment: tyring to find out why it fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you haven't seen that exact syntax. Look at what you've got:

```
db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12345);
```

That's calling `db.Parameters.Add` with an `int` argument. I suspect what you've *actually* seen is:

```
db.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 12345;
```

Or more simply:

```
db.Parameters.Add("@pID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12345;
```

In both cases, the `int` is *only* used to set the `Value` property on the parameter, after it's been created and added to the collection.

Your code only compiles because there's a [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136439(v=vs.110).aspx) overload - which should basically never be used, as far as I can see.

Comment: I thought I was creating a parameter, then assign value then add it to parameters collection. Thank you @JonSkeet